# Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function at wordpress autocomplete

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have the following function:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#campo_aeroporto").autocomplete({
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "aeroportos.php",
                            data: {
                                q: request.term
                            },
                            success: function (data) {
                                response(data);
                            }
                        })
                    },
                    minLength: 2
                });
            });
        </script>
```

but the console keeps accusing Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function, I already tryed using jQuery instead of $ and got no luck...

Comment: Is jQuery being included?

Answer (score 0):

Try with no-conflict wrappers:

```
(function($){   
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#campo_aeroporto").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "aeroportos.php",
                data: {
                    q: request.term
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data);
                }
             })
        },
        minLength: 2
    });
});
})(jQuery);
```